# If $A$ is Symmetric positive definite and $B$ is Skew-Symmetric, both real matrices ,is then $A+B$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been asked to prove or disprove that if $A$ is a real symmetric positive definite matrix and $B$ is a real skew-symmetrix matrix, then $A+B$ is invertible.
I am not sure if it is true, but my intuition says yes. Then my attempt to prove it is as follows:

Suppose that A+B is not invertible, then there is a vector $\vec{v}\neq 0$ such that $(A+B)\vec{v}=0$, then $A\vec{v}=-B\vec{v}$ and we have $\vec{v}^{T}A\vec{v}=-\vec{v}^{T}B\vec{v}$ and, after transposing, $\vec{v}^{T}A\vec{v}=\vec{v}^{T}B\vec{v}$ ,adding those we conclude that $\vec{v}^{T}A\vec{v}=0$, but this contradicts the positive definiteness of $A$, then $A+B$ is invertible.

Do you think my proof is correct?

Comment: Seems alright to me, though you should have gotten $v^TAv=-v^TBv$ instead and after transposing, you get $v^TAv=v^TBv$.